# How to draw transparent bitmap with IPicture::Render

Tags: c++, mfc, com

In MFC Application I am loading a bitmap  from resource using [OleLoadPicture](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/olectl/nf-olectl-oleloadpicture) function and drawing the bitmap using [IPicture::Render](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/api/ocidl/nf-ocidl-ipicture-render) function.

I want to draw transparent bitmap using IPicture . How to set transparent color to IPicture before Render() function?

Comment: Simple answer: You can't. If you need to render transparently, you cannot use `IPicture::Render`.

Comment: Try this: Call `IPicture::SelectPicture()` to select the bitmap into a memory device context, then call `AlphaBlend()` for rendering, specifying the memory DC as the source.

Comment: `Ole` word means 1990-1994 .No blending

Comment: @zett42: The OP is apparently trying to use key-color transparency. `AlphaBlend` does not offer that.

Comment: Sorry, I somehow skipped "set transparent color". In this case, replace `AlphaBlend` with `TransparentBlt`.

Comment: @zett42 Can u plz share some code regarding how to use
IPicture::SelectPicture() .I have gone through MSDN but not able to figure out this.